# Calculating a reverse Azimuth

Tags: qgis, azimuth

using QGIS 18.16
I am trying to figure out how to cal a reverse azimuth.  Basically the opposite direction.  So if i have a azimuth of 163, I subtract 180 which gives me -17.  I some how need to write a script or a field calc to then , for only the '-', numbers subtract that number form 360.  which would give me 343 as the reversed azimuth.

Comment: Can you specify what do you like to do (which software do you use)?

Comment: updated to state I am using QGIS 18.16

Comment: Try `if( "azimuth" < 180, "azimuth" + 180, "azimuth" - 180)`

Answer (score 2):

Try `if( "azimuth" < 180, "azimuth" + 180, "azimuth" - 180)`

[image]

Comment: @user12577 - did this solution work for you? Helpful (and rewarding!) to click the 'accept' check mark when answers are successful!